# Sending packets between Amazon EC2 instances using their MAC-addresses

Tags: ruby, networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Using this small ruby script + `packetfu`, I try to retransmit a broadcast packet to several hosts:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'packetfu'

dev = ARGV[0]
mac=`ip link show #{dev} | awk '/ether/ {print $2}'`
ARGV.shift
dests = ARGV

cap = PacketFu::Capture.new(
 :timeout => 4000,
 :iface => dev, :start => true,
 :filter => "ether src #{mac} and ether[0] & 1 = 1")

loop do
 cap.stream.each do |pkt|
    frame = PacketFu::IPPacket.parse(pkt)
    i = 0
    dests.each do |dest|
        frame.eth_daddr = dest
        frame.ip_header.ip_id = frame.ip_header.ip_id + i
        frame.ip_header.ip_sum = frame.ip_header.ip_calc_sum()
        frame.to_w(dev)
        i = i + 1
    end
 end
end
```

Using `tcpdump`, I see that they are retransmitted (sent several
times).

```
$ echo "foo" | netcat -ub 192.168.15.255 54321
```

On host1 (source host), tcpdump shows me at the moment:

```
12:19:30.602374 0a:f4:8d:75:e5:af > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 46: 192.168.15.17.36339 > 192.168.15.255.54321: UDP, length 4
12:19:30.605856 0a:f4:8d:75:e5:af > 0a:a2:5f:f1:de:e4, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 46: 192.168.15.17.36339 > 192.168.15.255.54321: UDP, length 4
12:19:30.608896 0a:f4:8d:75:e5:af > 0a:25:ef:2c:24:e3, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 46: 192.168.15.17.36339 > 192.168.15.255.54321: UDP, length 4
```

On `host2` (destination host, mac address `0a:a2:5f:f1:de:e4`), tcpdump shows nothing.

Security policy allows all traffic in the VPC.

Have you any ideas?
I'm sure that I miss some small thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I thank *Kenta Yasukawa* for the answer):

```
Have you turned off the source/destination check for your instances? By
default, EC2 instances drop an incoming packet whose destination address does
not match the receiver IP address. You can disable it by right-clicking on an
instance in Management console and select "Change Source / Destination check",
and click disable.
```

To disable the ckeck using EC API Tools:

```
$ ec2-modify-network-interface-attribute --source-dest-check False eni-8c8c9bca
```